# How to pass a string to a Windows command that expects a file argument?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, arguments

Suppose a program `cook` takes one argument: the pathname of a text file containing the recipe of the food to cook. Suppose I wish to call this program from within a `batch` script, also suppose I already have the recipe in a string variable:

```
set the_recipe = "wash cucumbers" "wash knife" "slice cucumbers"

cook ...  # What should I do here? It expects a file, but I only have a string.
```

Adapted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505828/how-to-pass-a-string-to-a-command-that-expects-a-file).

How can I pass the recipe to the command when it expects a filename argument?

I thought about creating a temporary file just for the purpose passing a file, but I wish to know if there are alternative ways to solve this problem.

Comment: As to your comment, please note e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/3001761

Comment: Fine to your last point. And no to this first point, as that is my own closed question.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the canned text isn't helpful in these cases - the point is don't just post the same question again.

Comment: You are telling a story instead of a minimal example/question. You have a variable instead of an file, it's unimportant for the question to imagine cooks, recipies or suppose what else could be

Comment: @LBogaardt Your question is downvoated because you are asking us ,to write the code for you which we do not do here.please take your question on a platform which write's  code for you or come again with a real programming related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Batch does not provide a mechanism similar to the Bourne shell heredoc. There are two ways to do this:

#### Option 1: Change the command

If you have access to the `cook` executable, you can add a flag to indicate passing a string or list of strings instead of a file. For example, `COOK/A` might take argument input, while `COOK/F` takes a file.

#### Option 2: Use a temporary file

Use a temporary file. The typical way to generate a temporary file is:

```
SET TEMPFILE=%TMP%\%~N0-%RANDOM%.tmp
ECHO.FILE CONTENT LINE 1 >> %TEMPFILE%
ECHO.FILE CONTENT LINE 2 >> %TEMPFILE%
REM AS MANY LINES AS ARE NEEDED
REM USE THE FILE
DEL/F "%TEMPFILE%" & REM DELETE THE TEMPORARY FILE
```

Remember that putting `""` in an `ECHO` statement will cause the quotation marks to be included in the file, and that `ECHO.` must be used to include an indent in the file.

If you mean to convert the variable in your example into a tempfile with each quoted segment on a separate line, you'll need to use `FOR`:

```
FOR %A IN (%THE_RECIPE%) DO (
  ECHO.%~A >> %TEMPFILE%
)
```

Including the `~` in the variable substitution strips out the quotation marks that would otherwise end up in the file. If you want the quotation marks in the file, you can omit the tilde.

Comment: Yeah, the tmp file would work, just not the ideal solution. I didn't know Windows did not provide a direct solution using 'print' or something similar to the Unix solution. Thanks Andrew!